# Looping "complex" object with ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I have the following "element":

```
public class ReportElementViewModel
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (_isChecked != value)
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel contains many ReportElementViewModels:

```
public abstract class ReportViewModel<TPrimaryModel> : SharedViewModel
    where TPrimaryModel : Model, new()
{       
    public ObservableCollection<ReportElementViewModel> ReportElementViewModels
    {
        get { return _reportElementViewModels; }
        set
        {
            if (_reportElementViewModels != value)
            {
                _reportElementViewModels = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ReportElementViewModels");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I removed the members to reduce code complexity but they are implemented correctly.

In my view I want to show all ReportElementViewModels by showing their `Name` and `IsChecked` (checkbox).

I thought the ItemsControl would be the right "tool", however it doesn't work (nothing is shown):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ReportElemetViewModels}" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="269"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a spelling mistake in your `Binding`.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ReportElemetViewModels}"
```

Should be:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ReportElementViewModels}"
```

Comment: That's embarrassing. Thank you!

Comment: If this solves your issue, please mark it as an answer.